# Export application from jelastic

Tags: java, deployment, glassfish, jelastic

I created glassfish server in jelastic environment. Now I can import(upload and deploy) my application to it.

The question is: How can I export(download to computer) that deployed application from the server.

Comment: Why would you want to? It should be the same application that you uploaded to deploy - so you already have a copy on your computer?

Comment: some times I get projects to support wich were developed by other developers. And they didn't leave the source code. So I want to export the project and decompile it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way for software development, in your case, is using the [version control system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control). Jelastic supports [deploy java project via GIT/SVN with Maven](https://docs.jelastic.com/maven-cloud-hosting-in-jelastic). With this solution, you will always have actual source code which can be deployed on Jelastic in any time.

Also, you can download your application using [Direct SSH Access to the Container](https://docs.jelastic.com/ssh-access#direct-access) or [SFTP/FISH Protocols](https://docs.jelastic.com/ssh-protocols).